# Remember select list option for onchange

Tags: javascript, onchange, html-select

Here is my code;

```
<select onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"> 
  <option value="">Select Something</option> 
  <option value="<?php echo site_url(); ?>">Home</option> 
  <option value="<?php echo site_url(); ?>publications">Publications</option> 
  <option value="<?php echo site_url(); ?>contact_us">Contact Us</option> 
</select>
```

When an option is selected, that page will immediately load. However, the drop-down list does not "remember" that that option was selected. The drop-down list will just default back to Select Something. How can I get the list to display what was selected instead?

Before I began using Frameworks I might have tried something like this;

`<option value="<?php echo site_url(); ?>contact_us" <?php if($value == "contact_us") {echo "selected"; } ?> >Contact Us</option>`

And I would have created a $value using $_REQUEST['value'] or something. But I am using the CodeIgniter framework so I don't think I can do that anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you:

```
<?php if($value == $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) {echo "selected"; } ?>
```

I suggest from your code that you have some php `$value`-es equal to every option value. So, you can compare it with web page URI

[More about $_SERVER global](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)